# Windows 10 can't restart after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu from a usb to my Windows 10 drive and partitioned it for Ubuntu to dual-boot. After installing it, I rebooted and the grub menu to choose between Windows and Ubuntu appeared the first time. After choosing windows, I tried to reboot it and it's stuck on the restarting screen. Is it because I installed it on the same drive? Something about ext4 and Windows clashing?

How do I start repairing it? From Windows or Ubuntu? and how?

Comment: ubuntu installer can't/wont affect windows partitions or windows short. you have nothing to fear from it. windows having issues booting is unrelated. grub does not reboot when selecting an option. Did you press the restart button on your case or something? why ? have you tried simply letting it load after selecting windows?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @RodSmith alright, will do

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar problem yesterday with a laptop running W7 and used this supergrub burned CD to reboot in windows and create a repair CD with which I fixed the MBR and boot sector so it has only Windows 7 again.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Might help you out.

Max